# Change my Circular Progress-Bar into half circle

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I have `Circular Progress-Bar`:

```
    <Grid>
        <Path x:Name="pathRoot" Stroke="{Binding SegmentColor, ElementName=userControl}"
          StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness, ElementName=userControl}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure x:Name="pathFigure">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <ArcSegment x:Name="arcSegment" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CircularProgressBar.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CircularProgressBar : UserControl
{
    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Angle = (Percentage * 360) / 100;
        RenderArc();
    }

    public int Radius
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush SegmentColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(SegmentColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SegmentColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public int StrokeThickness
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Percentage
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PercentageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PercentageProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Angle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Percentage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PercentageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Percentage", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(65d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPercentageChanged)));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StrokeThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(1));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SegmentColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SegmentColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SegmentColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(80, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(120d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnPercentageChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        CircularProgressBar circle = sender as CircularProgressBar;
        circle.Angle = (circle.Percentage * 360) / 100;
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        CircularProgressBar circle = sender as CircularProgressBar;
        circle.RenderArc();
    }

    public void RenderArc()
    {
        Point startPoint = new Point(Radius, 0);
        Point endPoint = ComputeCartesianCoordinate(Angle, Radius);
        endPoint.X += Radius;
        endPoint.Y += Radius;

        pathRoot.Width = Radius * 2 + StrokeThickness;
        pathRoot.Height = Radius * 2 + StrokeThickness;
        pathRoot.Margin = new Thickness(StrokeThickness, StrokeThickness, 0, 0);

        bool largeArc = Angle > 180.0;

        Size outerArcSize = new Size(Radius, Radius);

        pathFigure.StartPoint = startPoint;

        if (startPoint.X == Math.Round(endPoint.X) && startPoint.Y == Math.Round(endPoint.Y))
            endPoint.X -= 0.01;

        arcSegment.Point = endPoint;
        arcSegment.Size = outerArcSize;
        arcSegment.IsLargeArc = largeArc;
    }

    private Point ComputeCartesianCoordinate(double angle, double radius)
    {
        // convert to radians
        double angleRad = (Math.PI / 180.0) * (angle - 90);

        double x = radius * Math.Cos(angleRad);
        double y = radius * Math.Sin(angleRad);

        return new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

This controller works find but i want to change a little this shape and i am wonder if it possible to change this `Circle` into `Half Circle`, i try to change several properties like `Angle` but my `Circle` hasn't changed.
Is it possible to do that or i need to change the whole class ?

Comment: There are places where `Percentage * 360` should probably be `Percentage * 180`. Try that.

Comment: OK that's works but now i have only the right side of my circle and i want to upper side

Comment: I'm no maths expert, but I think what you're looking for is here: `Point startPoint = new Point(Radius, 0);`, and here: `Point endPoint = ComputeCartesianCoordinate(Angle, Radius);`.